# Master to update multiple worksheets, cut and paste to sheet according to value

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to create a workbook, that will cut and paste a row to a sheet depending on the value.

Value - paid or pending

sheets master, paid and pending

When I update column E on master to either paid or pending, I need it deleted from master and put in the relevant sheet (paid or pending).

I've scoured the net looking for a solution and not found anything I can modify.

Please help.

I've tried using the code below, but I just get the whole master sheet copied to the paid sheet.

Could anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim i, LastRow

LastRow = Sheets("Main").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Outstanding").Range("A2:I10485").ClearContents
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "E").Value = "Pending" Then
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Outstanding").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If

LastRow = Sheets("Main").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Paid").Range("A2:I50000").ClearContents
If Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "E").Value = "Paid" Then
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Paid").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

The headers are
 Card   Amount  Date    Due Date    Status

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=zjKRVfSoF4GI8Qf78YG4Cg#q=automatically+move+a+record+in+excel+upon+update
One of these results might be just what you are looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grrETxZrks4

Comment: Exhausted Mr Google.. Almost bought the internet to  standstill.

Comment: thanks for the link, I'll take a gander :)